# Service console is not behaving properly in sandbox

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console

I am working with a `Visualforce Page` that I have to display in a service console in a new tab. The functionality is working fine in my developer org service console. In the sandbox console the new tab is getting open the but the page is not getting displayed.

Comment: Can you check out all necessary permissions in sandbox?

Comment: can you be a little specific about permission in sandbox. Because i have checked for all permission on profile and user interface. Is there any place that i have to check for?